# What is the use of intents and context in android

Tags: android

I am new to android My question is what are intents and context in Android. I am not able to find out there use in android application why they are used when they are used .For me as a beginner these are quite confusing. I had read many Articles but I am not able to determine there meaning and I am not able to use them flexibly can any body help me any help would very appreciable. Thanks for reading

Comment: Intents are basically the objects that contains the information. Intents are just passed from one activity to another.. our android system to one activity. so as to pass messages. Intents are of two types explicit and implicit. In other words you can say intents are the messages. Android system get to know about different views , differnt activities of diffrent applications through context only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read [Android Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) to understand them.